# MySQL maximum 10 rows for single geographical area

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with **mysql** database.

I have this table with **122 rows** and columns `OrderTco` and `OrderCode`.

`OrderTco` is the geographical area of origin of an order, `OrderCode` is a code of order that for the same geographical area can be repeated.

I need to extract from this table maximum 10 rows for single geographical area.

I need this output in which for area A1 extracted all rows (*because I have only 9 rows*), for area B1 and area C1 the first 10 rows:

```
+-----+----------+-----------+
| ID  | OrderTco | OrderCode |
+-----+----------+-----------+
|   1 | A1       |  47421842 |
|   2 | A1       |  48062487 |
|   3 | A1       |  48889676 |
|   4 | A1       |  50384199 |
|   5 | A1       |  50887328 |
|   6 | A1       |  50918700 |
|   7 | A1       |  51248220 |
|   8 | A1       |  51794088 |
|   9 | A1       |  90817292 |
|  10 | B1       |  41771826 |
|  11 | B1       |  44723830 |
|  12 | B1       |  45483247 |
|  13 | B1       |  46148815 |
|  14 | B1       |  46514834 |
|  15 | B1       |  46834766 |
|  16 | B1       |  46834770 |
|  17 | B1       |  47615351 |
|  18 | B1       |  47615653 |
|  19 | B1       |  47802697 |
|  60 | C1       |  42156626 |
|  61 | C1       |  46156395 |
|  62 | C1       |  47099964 |
|  63 | C1       |  47737295 |
|  64 | C1       |  48672260 |
|  65 | C1       |  49048345 |
|  66 | C1       |  49370148 |
|  67 | C1       |  50781626 |
|  68 | C1       |  51580145 |
|  69 | C1       |  51580146 |
+-----+----------+-----------+
```

I thought of a grouping by `OrderTco`, `OrderCode` and Limit 10 but I can not have the output.

My table below.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dotable`;
CREATE TABLE `dotable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OrderTco` char(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderCode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=123 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('1', 'A1', '47421842');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('2', 'A1', '48062487');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('3', 'A1', '48889676');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('4', 'A1', '50384199');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('5', 'A1', '50887328');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('6', 'A1', '50918700');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('7', 'A1', '51248220');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('8', 'A1', '51794088');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('9', 'A1', '90817292');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('10', 'B1', '41771826');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('11', 'B1', '44723830');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('12', 'B1', '45483247');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('13', 'B1', '46148815');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('14', 'B1', '46514834');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('15', 'B1', '46834766');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('16', 'B1', '46834770');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('17', 'B1', '47615351');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('18', 'B1', '47615653');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('19', 'B1', '47802697');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('20', 'B1', '48069101');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('21', 'B1', '48215307');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('22', 'B1', '48287092');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('23', 'B1', '48361996');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('24', 'B1', '48610861');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('25', 'B1', '48881052');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('26', 'B1', '48990004');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('27', 'B1', '49170385');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('28', 'B1', '49810778');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('29', 'B1', '49864962');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('30', 'B1', '50093254');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('31', 'B1', '50150294');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('32', 'B1', '50151510');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('33', 'B1', '50669799');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('34', 'B1', '50948841');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('35', 'B1', '51096692');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('36', 'B1', '51096793');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('37', 'B1', '51848609');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('38', 'B1', '52018758');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('39', 'B1', '52129746');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('40', 'B1', '89318652');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('41', 'B1', '89969871');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('42', 'B1', '89969874');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('43', 'B1', '89969885');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('44', 'B1', '89969887');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('45', 'B1', '89984300');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('46', 'B1', '90642243');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('47', 'B1', '90642246');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('48', 'B1', '90656056');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('49', 'B1', '90681042');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('50', 'B1', '90686901');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('51', 'B1', '90687088');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('52', 'B1', '90694120');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('53', 'B1', '90771866');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('54', 'B1', '90829027');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('55', 'B1', '90866489');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('56', 'B1', '90938371');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('57', 'B1', '90949259');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('58', 'B1', '91125485');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('59', 'B1', '91174802');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('60', 'C1', '42156626');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('61', 'C1', '46156395');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('62', 'C1', '47099964');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('63', 'C1', '47737295');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('64', 'C1', '48672260');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('65', 'C1', '49048345');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('66', 'C1', '49370148');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('67', 'C1', '50781626');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('68', 'C1', '51580145');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('69', 'C1', '51580146');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('70', 'C1', '51590131');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('71', 'C1', '51593663');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('72', 'C1', '52110407');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('73', 'C1', '88959568');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('74', 'C1', '89107949');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('75', 'C1', '89559925');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('76', 'C1', '89822330');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('77', 'C1', '89853401');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('78', 'C1', '89875109');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('79', 'C1', '90143788');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('80', 'C1', '90147121');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('81', 'C1', '90261952');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('82', 'C1', '90262117');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('83', 'C1', '90268972');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('84', 'C1', '90349287');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('85', 'C1', '90350763');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('86', 'C1', '90354055');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('87', 'C1', '90388795');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('88', 'C1', '90424846');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('89', 'C1', '90498839');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('90', 'C1', '90503670');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('91', 'C1', '90508353');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('92', 'C1', '90518025');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('93', 'C1', '90520214');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('94', 'C1', '90546077');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('95', 'C1', '90546078');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('96', 'C1', '90554790');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('97', 'C1', '90554800');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('98', 'C1', '90565102');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('99', 'C1', '90571253');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('100', 'C1', '90631905');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('101', 'C1', '90631971');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('102', 'C1', '90656093');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('103', 'C1', '90660564');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('104', 'C1', '90669061');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('105', 'C1', '90669309');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('106', 'C1', '90685269');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('107', 'C1', '90687702');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('108', 'C1', '90767056');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('109', 'C1', '90767745');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('110', 'C1', '90768541');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('111', 'C1', '90902399');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('112', 'C1', '90902528');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('113', 'C1', '90908367');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('114', 'C1', '90908789');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('115', 'C1', '90929476');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('116', 'C1', '90929477');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('117', 'C1', '90929718');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('118', 'C1', '91038039');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('119', 'C1', '91056217');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('120', 'C1', '91056340');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('121', 'C1', '91087005');
INSERT INTO `dotable` (OrderTco, OrderCode) VALUES ('122', 'C1', '91139612');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select dt.*
from dotable dt
where (select count(*)
       from dotable dt2
       where dt2.OrderTco = dt. OrderTco and
             dt2.id <= dt.id
      ) <= 10
```

You can also do this with variables, but with such a small table, the above query should be fine.

Comment: thank you for help. I have tried your method but in the output I have 95 rows instead of 29 and don't have rows for area A1....